# C++ % operator not working

Tags: c++

In this c++ program I made that lists all the divisors of a number defined by user input I use the % operator to check if there is a remainder.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"List divisors of: ";
    cin>>n;
    for (int a=1;a<n;a++)
    {       
        if ((a % n)==0)
        {
        cout<<a<<"- divisor of "<<n<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<a<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the `if ((a % n)==0)` condition is never met so the output of typing 10 would be:

```
List divisors of: 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can you display multiples by iterating from 1 to N? Multiple means something larger than N, like 2*N, 3*N, etc... Do you mean divisors?

Comment: The remainder of 1/10 is 1, 2/10 is 2, 3/10 is 3, you're never going to reach 0 stopping at 9.

Comment: Why do you think everything from 1 to 9 is a multiple of 10?

Comment: @Cristy yes  thanks I meant divisors

Comment: @sftrabbit thats the output of it before I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Arithmetic. No number greater than 0 and lower than `n` is a multiple of `n`. In order for the operation `a % n` to give `0` as a result, there must exist a number `k` such that `k * n = a`. But since `a` is greater than 0 and always less than `n`, there can be no such `k`.

Perhaps you meant to write `((n % a) == 0)` instead, which would be true every time `n` is a multiple of `a` (so if you assign the value `10` to `n`, the condition in your loop will be true when `a` has value `1`, `2`, or `5`).

Comment: Except 0 and negative multiples. :D

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
 if ((a % n)==0)

 to  if ((n % a)==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is all the *divisors* of a number. Try swapping the numbers: `if ((n % a) == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maths my dear boy. Maths.

12 divided by 10 is 1 remainder 2.

8 divided by 10 is 0 remainder 8.